# uploadify - files below 8MB work, bigger don't

Tags: php, uploadify

I'm using uploadify v.3.2, which i used in an older project as well, there it works fine!

But now i'm trying to upload files up to 500 MB on another server. But the script only uploads files up to 7.9 MB...

My php-info tells:

upload_max_filesize 512M

post_max_size   512M

And this is the script I'm using in my HTML-Template:

```
        $(function() {
            $('#data').uploadify({
                'formData'     : {
                'timestamp' : '1349443065',
                'token'     : '94a031393fe2f786fdfc14c0cd432204'
                },
                'swf'      : './includes/uploadify.swf',
                'uploader' : './includes/uploadify.php',
'buttonText' : 'choose file',
'onUploadSuccess' : function(file, data, response) {
            alert('Die Datei ' + file.name + ' wurde erfolgreich hochgeladen!'); },
'checkExisting' : './includes/check-exists.php'
            });
        });
```

this is the code of the uploadify.php:

```
// Define a destination
$targetFolder = '/upload'; // Relative to the root

$verifyToken = md5('unique_salt' . $_POST['timestamp']);

if (!empty($_FILES) && $_POST['token'] == $verifyToken) {
    $tempFile = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
    $targetPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $targetFolder;
    $targetFile = rtrim($targetPath,'/') . '/' . $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];

    // Validate the file type
    $fileTypes = array('zip','rar','sit'); // File extensions
    $fileParts = pathinfo($_FILES['Filedata']['name']);

$dateiname = $targetFile;   
$ersetzen = '/homepages/37/d24392003/htdocs/modx/upload/';
$dateiname = str_replace($ersetzen, "", $dateiname);    

    if (in_array($fileParts['extension'],$fileTypes)) {
        move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);
        mail('123@abc.com', 'Dateiupload', "Es wurde eine neue Datei hochgeladen\n\nDateiname: $dateiname", "from:123@abc.de");
    } else {
        echo 'Invalid file type.';
    }
}
```

So the script works, the php-configuration seems fine...anyone has any tipps what to do?

Cheers!

Comment: Can you take uploadify out of the equation and test with a basic HTML form? This will determine whether or not it's your php configuration or not.

Comment: hi r3mus...don't know what you mean by your post? sorry...

Comment: Can you build a very basic HTML form that uploads your 500MB file to the server? A dead simple tutorial: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp This will ensure that your php installation is indeed set up to handle the supposed 512M limit that it's configured to do. I've seen bizarre overrides in places that while php reports the right upload limit, the php.ini file isn't being honored.

Comment: this seems to work...no error after upload...but we didn't tell where to save the file, so i can't find my testfile anywhere...

Answer (score 1):

Set the file size limit as an option: `'fileSizeLimit' : '500MB',`

```
$(function() {
    $('#data').uploadify({
        ...

        'fileSizeLimit' : '500MB', // added this, set to whatever value you like

        ...
    });
});
```

**Then add this** to your main `.htaccess` file to override any default restrictions on your server (includes overriding your `php.ini` file):

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 500M
php_value post_max_size 500M
```

***If you are getting*** `500 - Internal Server Error`, that likely means you don't have permission to set these values by `.htaccess`. You'll have to contact your web server provider. Ask them to allow you to set `AllowOverride` options.

**OPTION B:**

Create a `php.ini` file and store in the same root directory as your `.htaccess` file. Add the two lines above and see if that works. If you're getting a `500 Internal` error using the last method, this probably won't work either. But you can try.

Comment: thx for your reply...i tried this already without success...the script says "upload successful", but no file in the folder (unless it's bigger than 7.9MB)

Comment: is this Wordpress website by any chance?

Comment: adding those lines to the .htaccess leads to Error 500...maybe a link might help? http://www.profilneurotiker.com/plug-dj.html ...btw. thx for helping!

Comment: i already have a php.ini file, which increases the post_max_filesize and the upload_max_filesize...without this i won't have 512MB in each setting

Comment: Contact your service provider then...I'm assuming your using a Shared Hosting account. This is the issue they'll sort out for you. Just state what I wrote in my answer for a smooth transition. :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try seeing if your php.ini settings were actually loaded, using `phpinfo();`? Look at which `php.ini` file was loaded.

Lastly, from my experience, if the correct php.ini file is loaded but the changes do not appear, try re-installing PHP, as a **last resort**.

Hope this helps!

Comment: thx kxc1013! my php.ini settings are working, there i tell the server to increase the upload_max_filesize and post_max_filesize and my php-info tells me that these settings are made